# Not getting the attribute in jsp which is set in request in java servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using gwt and the gwt is including in my jsp like below

Once i clicked the menu item it is taking me to myJsp.jsp which includes gwt module and i am displaying form with upload button.
Once i click the  upload, it is uloading a file (and get the blobKey) and returns back to the same jsp(myJsp.jsp) but here before dispatching to this jsp(second time) i am setting one attribute in the request.

I am trying to get that attribute in the jsp by using ${ImportId} but i am getting empty value.

The below is my jsp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/ActivityLog/ActivityLog.nocache.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' class="iframe"></iframe>
    <div class="wrapper"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="memcacheHeaderId" value="${importId}" />
      <div id="activityLogModule">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. When ever executing gwt module  ${importId} is null.
2. Second time before dispatching to this jsp, i am setting   `request.setAttribute("importId", importId);` but in the jsp i am not getting this value

What might be the reason, Is there scope problem?

Answer (score 1):

the only reason is you are setting value in request, as your request is completed, server discard your request.

Comment: So how do i can do that?

Comment: Can you please give me more description

Answer (score 0):

when you are setting

> request.setAttribute("importId", importId);

Than you must be redirecting to the JSP, which creates a new Request for the JSP to the Server. Meaning server creates a new request object and does not remembers the old object with your  attribute set into it.

I am not much aware of gwt but in JSP-Servlet, there are 2 mechanisms 1)Redirect and 2)Forward. we use Forward mechanism to go to the JSP with the Same request object, so the attribute which is set into the Object is available on the JSP as well, because it is a copy of the request object passed in the Request.

So please check what you can do in GWT.